# How to Call Oracle stored procedure through liquibase Changelog File XML

Tags: database, oracle, database-migration, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am using following syntax in Changelog file

```
<changeSet author="demouser" id="demochangeset333" dbms="oracle">
    <sql>CALL LiquiInsert('ABC','1.0.3.4','ABC');</sql>
</changeSet>
```

It get call well from sqlplus that is outside of liquibase but gives Error

> ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name session is altered correctly

This work fine from outside ..

Open to suggestions..

Procedure consists of just an `insert` statement - nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`<changeSet author="demouser" id="demochangeset333" dbms="oracle">
    <sql>
         begin
            execute LiquiInsert('ABC','1.0.3.4','ABC');
         end;
    </sql>
</changeSet>`

Comment: I think you need to add splitStatements="false" within sql tag in order to avoid liquibase executing each line independently.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<sqlFile
path=“xxx.sql”
relativeToChangelogFile=“true”
stripComments=“true”
splitStatements=“false”
endDelimiter=“/”
dbms=“oracle”
/>
```

and .sql file should have

```
BEGIN
    package.function();
END;
/
```